# How do I add/append data from an excel sheet to a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, import

The Excel sheet is huge; contains around 40,000 rows. Both the table and the excel sheet have an equal number of columns.
I am using Ubuntu Linux, Libre Office and MySQL workbench. All I could find when I searched on the web was to import using MySQL Server Studio(I don't think it is available for Ubuntu), and queries containing "Microsoft.Jet-OPENROWSET" query. I am new to performing tasks other than the basic operations in excel/SQL.

And also, what format should the excel be in? Should it contain the column names explicitly?

Is there a simple way to perform this operation?

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: The method I use, which may not be optimal, but has a fine level of control, is to write a formula for the first row along the lines of `="insert into table values ("&a2&","&b2&");"` for example. Once I have it working, I copy it down, then paste the results into mysql workbench...

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. But the problem is I have 40,000 rows. Won't this query get slowed down or stuck?

Comment: I've used it may times from a few rows up to 60,000 rows. Ok, it took a few minutes, but it was for a data load, so once off. (Are you doing this regularly? In which case an automated solution would be much better.)

Comment: Ah, OK. No, it's just a one-time thing. I will try this out.

Comment: @wwkudu It works!! Thanks! (It did take a few minutes like you said)

Comment: Cool, glad to hear it. I use it all the time for generating test data too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/your/file'  INTO TABLE tablename
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' lines terminated by '\n';
```